# The Dirac Hamiltonian

Tags: operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

I know I can apply the Hamiltonian operator $H$ to the eigenvector and I get the energy of the state. I would like to know if the Dirac Hamiltonian works the same way. I would also like to know whether I can use the Dirac Hamiltonian to find out whether the state has positive or negative energy.